# text and image in new tab

Tags: html, text, tabs

The goal is to add text along with an image that is demonstrated on a new tab. I have tried several methods for the text but none seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<div id="imagelist">
  <div class="content_img">
    <a href="images/belle_rose_3.png" target="_blank">
      <img id="table-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
      <div>Old as Time</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div><!-- missing closing tag added by community -->
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and see [ask]. It's not clear what problem you're having.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are trying to ask. Are you trying to show the image in a new tab?

Comment: sorry, First time using this website. I was able to get the new tab with target=_blank however I am not sure what I can use in order to place the text with the image.

Answer (score 0):

Opening a new window is seen as a pop-up and many modern browsers now block pop-ups. However, if pop-ups are not blocked the following will work (try it by just pasting it into your browser console - if your browser does not block pop-ups).

```
win = window.open();
win.document.body.innerHTML = `<div style="font-size: 5vh; display: flex; justify-content: center; place-items: center; width: 100%; height: 100vh;">Your images may go here</div>`;
```